# Combobox / Autocomplete binding in a Dataform Silverlight 4 application

Tags: silverlight-4.0, combobox, ria, silverlight-toolkit, dataform

Why is it so hard to find a simple example of a binding of a combobox inside a dataform which fetches values from another table (ID, Description lookup) !!  Most of microsoft's tutorials only show simple dataform CRUD but with no combo/autocomplete lookups.  I do not want to use MVVM, just a simple code behind example with Entity Framework 4 with RIA Services.  I have been looking for days... I have a domain context, etc... I know there was issues with comboxbox binding in SL3 but now in SL4 it seems fixed.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am switching to Lightswitch. I know it is not as customizable but is good for my needs.  It actually does this is a snap. thanks.